# Modulo double check

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I'm working on some math, and this is the equation that I have to write an extensive computer program for. Wolfram Alpha gives this same answer, so I just want to double check to know WHY this is the answer before I spend a month working on it. Here is the equation:

c = $65^{17}$ mod 3233 = 2790

So, as far as I'm able to tell, the equation is stating: take 65 to the power of 17, take that result and divide it by 3233, and the remainder is 2790. Am I correct? If not, what is the problem stating? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should really be a comment- but I do not have enough reps to make it into a comment.

What you wrote is absolutely correct.

Comment: haha alright awesome! thanks :) for sure upvote and selected for those reps :P

Comment: @voldemort, how have you derived this?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee: This is the definition of mod. m mod n = k means that if you divide m by n then you get k as the remainder. He already got the answer from Wolfram alpha. I didn't do the calculation.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is correct, but if you are writing a computer program for it, you probably don't want to implement it that way. The number $65^{17}$ is quite large, on the order of $10^{30}$ which is larger than will fit in a 64-bit integer type on a computer.

The idea with these modular arithmetic problems is to take the remainder after each multiplication so that the number remains small. In other words, compute $65 \times 65 \pmod{3233}$ and then multiply that by 65 and take the remainder mod 3233, etc.

You can actually make it even more efficient by just squaring the number four times and then multiplying by 65. In other words, think of it as

$$ 65^{17} = 65 (((65^2)^2)^2)^2.$$

So you can do it in just five multiplications and five remainders mod 3233.